# Font changes within Announcement list - modal view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, modal-dialog

relatively easy question I have here and was hoping someone could help me out. I have tried to find the particular classes to update the standard SharePoint font (8pt, Verdana) within the body of an announcement (that opens in the modal view) and have had no luck. I am referring to the **Title, Body, Expires** headings and the *acquired text* for those headings.

I had run IE developer tools and tried to update a few classes inherited from corev4.css in my custom css but got nowhere. I could see the styles to the standard SP font Verdana, 8pt and color on a few classes, tried to change them but obviously not finding the right ones. I think from memory they were:

- ms-formtoolbar
- ms-formlabel
- ms-formbody
- ms-rtestate-field

I also studied Heather Solomons chart back to front and couldnt find anything on there that referred to this.

Would really love if someone could tell me the classes I need to update

Thanks guys

Comment: Please does anyone know, its driving me nuts